# WooCommerce plugin is failed to activate

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

WooCommerce plugin is failed to activate due to following error reported....

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\myWebsite\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-core-functions.php on line 1805

Comment: Please try re-installing [woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/)

Comment: @mujuonly , reinstalled but same problem